# How does an MRI work?

Tags: quantum-chemistry

This is my interpretation of an MRI:

There's an external magnetic field and most of the hydrogen nuclei will align themselves with that field (which is the lower energy state) but some are not aligned (which is the higher energy state). A chemist can then direct a wide range of radio waves with different wavelengths. The specific wavelength that causes the hydrogen nuclei to go from their lower energy aligned state to their higher energy unaligned state can be determined by the wavelength of the energy emitted by the photon when the hydrogen nuclei return to its ground state. And that wavelength determines the environment. Is this accurate?

Comment: That's more like a very old form of NMR. Modern NMR is a tiny bit more complicated than that. MRI, on the other hand, is substantially more complicated, because you need to figure out exactly *where* that molecule you detected was; it's not enough to know its chemical environment, you also need to pinpoint its location. Why are you asking this, and what's your background? Is there something specific you're looking for? It's unlikely that we can give you a general treatise on MRI here. I'd suggest looking for a book.

Comment: @orthocresol I'm a grade 12 chemistry student so I assume the explanation I'm looking for is quite basic. Just looking for a brief, simple explanation that will help me gain some insight. Thanks

Comment: Sam, there is no emission of a photon by a proton. It is a major misconception you will in webpages on NMR.

Comment: @M.Farooq When a photon strikes a hydrogen nucleus and causes it to rise to a higher energy level. Will the nucleus not emit a photon when it returns to its ground state?

Comment: Actually, I had asked this from a very big name in NMR spectroscopy. He said "no". It is a myth created by MRI people. I have discussed this question in SE Chemistry.

Comment: @M.Farooq I would argue for the existence of photons, they are by definition the "force carriers" of the electromagnetic field. It adds unnecessary confusion to argue about this very useful idea. There is an assumption here that because MRI is an amazing advanced tool it cannot be explained in terms of simple concepts. I think in this particular case that is incorrect.

Comment: Protons do not flip their spin 1/2 without accepting spin from or passing it to a spin 1 photon. Both spin energy levels are about equally distributed, but with slight energy difference levels, belonging to photons of radio frequency. Lower energy spin absorbs such a photon,  higher level one emits such a photon. Chemical neighbourhood affects specifically the local value of magnetic induction and therefore the proportional spin energy level difference. It is similar to electron levels in UV/VIS, but in different energy, frequency and wavelength region.

Comment: @BuckThorn, I agree it is a very complex phenomenon. The person who told me that photon "emission" should not be included in the NMR detection was one of the leading editors of Concepts in Magnetic Resonance. I respect his view point. I had this misconception as well. He said that photon myth was spread MRI people. There are many articles on this topic.

Comment: @BuckThorn, I think NMR receiver coil is like an antenna. I don't think antenna engineers like to invoke photons. I had a similar dilemma in microwave emission spectroscopy. What is the horn antenna detecting?

Comment: @MFarooq It just feels like barking up the wrong tree and creating unnecessary confusion to argue about photons, because single quantum transitions are useful to understanding the QM basics underlying NMR. Granted the picture of a single discrete H nucleus undergoing a transition quickly loses importance as you dwell into details of NMR.

Comment: Also, those nuclei don't know you placed a loop around them (to a first approx), and photons are associated with the electromagnetic field one way or another, even if they might lose their meaning as spatially or temporally localized entities.

Comment: As pointed out by Poutnik, the population difference between two energy levels is very small (the energy difference is very small compared to kT).

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to detect where a spin in a sample is is to place this in a magnetic field that changes in direct proportion to depth. Then the frequency at which spins respond to the r.f. radiation can be interpreted as a depth. Clearly it is going to be far more complex to get 3D images but in essence is the same; the detected signal has to be encoded with a position.

Answer (score 1):

That's a reasonable description of chemical shift based resolution in NMR, and also describes an important aspect of how one-dimensional imaging is performed. There is an additional important concept, phase. MRI relies on phase-shifting signals from different voxels (volumes of the sample) using pulsed magnetic-field gradients. These gradients are applied after the nuclei have been excited. They are also applied during detection of the signal. The gradients alter the magnitude of the field in which individual nuclei find themselves, and therefore the energy (or resonant frequency) of the photons emitted. Different energies can be mapped to different locations in the sample.

The following image shows an example MRI pulse sequence (source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MRI_sequence)). Time is shown along the abscissa. There is one RF channel and three gradient channels. The RF channel is used to excite the signal (first pulse labelled $\pi/2$) or trigger spin echoes ($\pi$), while the gradient channels encode position by shifting the phase prior to acquisition (channels Gy and Gz) or the frequency during (channel Gx) signal acquisition.

[image]